# How to see all the tables in an HSQLDB database?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I usually use SQLDeveloper to browse the database, but I couldn't make it work with HSQLDB and I don't know which tables are already created…
I guess it's a vendor-specific question and not plain SQL, but the point is: how can I see the tables so I can drop/alter them?

Comment: What database are you using.  The answer depends greatly.

Comment: Sorry, I added a tag but I forgot to mention that I'm using Hsqldb

Comment: Honestly, the title told me what the BDMS is.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The ANSI SQL92 standard for querying database metadata is contained within the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` data structures.

I have no idea whether your database supports this or not, but try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

On further research, it appears that HSQLDB does support `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but with slightly non-standard naming.

All of the tables have `SYSTEM_*` prepended to them, so the above example would read

```
SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES
```

I have no means of testing this, and the answer was found on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=5978227).

Comment: So I just need to add where TABLE_TYPE = 'TABLE' and I got it... thanks for your help! And the good news, according to the link you posted is that, for new versions, they will go follow the standard. Thanks again.

Comment: Table not found: TABLES in statement [SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES]

Comment: HSQLDB 2.x supports both forms of SELECT given in the answer.

Comment: Dose the query syntax can execute in HSQL database manager? I enter the query syntax into it, but as cherouvim cited, Table not found:...Error Code -22/State:s0002.

Comment: SELECT * FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES; worked for me with a copy of the subsonic.org database.  To get just the user tables add the where clause: SELECT * FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='TABLE';

Comment: with `hsqlDB` you can do a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable (column details...)` if you only wanted to be sure before creating a new one.

Answer (score 14):

Awesome, thanks! Been scouring the Web for that info.
This will fetch only your tables' field info:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, TYPE_NAME, COLUMN_SIZE, DECIMAL_DIGITS, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'SYSTEM_%'
```

You can retrieve indexes, primary key info, all kinds of stuff from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES`.
Gotta love oo documentation :p

Comment: there is no table in HSQLDB after executed using  SELECT ... FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'SYSTEM_%' in jdbc:hsqldb:mem: as URL connection. So it's connecting format is not for query, but it can connect in back end, right?

Comment: That query works perfectly, saved me some time. I'm using HSQL 2.3.2

Answer (score 4):

If you're on the command line, you may want to try the Hsqldb SqlTool, documented in the [SqlTool Manual](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html) (hsqldb.org).

- Put your database connection information in "`~/sqltool.rc`" and choose any DBNAME you want, substitute correct username and password, if known.

  - `urlid DBNAME`
  - `url jdbc:hsqldb:/path/to/hsql/database`
  - username SA
  - password
- Install tool with: `apt-get install hsqldb-utils` (on Ubuntu)
- Connect with `hsqldb-sqltool DBNAME` # on Ubuntu
- Hint for other systems: `java -jar YourHsqlJar.jar DBNAME`
- Show tables with: `\dt`
- Show columns with: \d TABLENAME
- Standard queries like: `SELECT * FROM …;`
- Edit (append) last command with: `:a`
- Quit with: `\q`
- View special commands with: `\?` OR `:?`

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\dt` command when you hit the `>sql` prompt in the command line for HSQLDB.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DBVisualiser](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/) and [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). Both of these have support for HSQLDB, and a GUI for editing/modifying/viewing the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You run querying using `hsql database manager`, are you?
If you use this, below may give some hints:

Select your connection:

1. type: `HSQL DATABASE ENGINE SERVER`
2. Driver: `jdbc.hsqldb.jdbcDriver`
3. URL: `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/`

Then, you will browse the database.