# HSQLDB : Test presence of a column in a table

Tags: hsqldb

Is there a way to send an SQL query to HSQLDB (edit : *prior to version 2*) to know the columns of a certain table ? (Similar to the inspection of the schemas through INFORMATION_SCHEMA in MySQL.)

Right now it seems to me I'm stuck with trying to `SELECT column_name FROM table_name` and see if I get an SQL error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDB supports the INFORMATION_SCHEMA as well:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_information_schema

Comment: Hmm ok, I'm having an old version of HSQLDB then. :)

Comment: Versions of HSQLDB since 1.8 support INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The table you should query is INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS. Even older versions support the same table but no schemas.

Answer (score 1):

You use queries to the special SYSTEM tables. See the answers to [this question].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591518/how-to-see-all-the-tables-in-an-hsqldb-database)