# how to connect to a file based HSQLDB database with sqltool?

Tags: hsqldb

I have tried to follow the instructions in [chapter 1 of the HSQLDB doc](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html) and started my server like:

```
java -cp hsqldb-2.2.5/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 file:#pathtodb# -dbname.0 xdb
```

and I have reason to believe that worked cause it said (among other things):

```
Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:#pathtodb#, alias=xdb] opened sucessfully in 2463 ms.
```

However at the next step I try to connect using SqlTool and based on [chapter 8 of the documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch08.html) I came up with this command to connect:

```
java -jar hsqldb-2.2.5/hsqldb/lib/sqltool.jar localhost-sa
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Failed to get a connection to 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost' as user "SA".
Cause: General error: database alias does not exist
```

while the server says:

```
 [Server@60072ffb]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @4ceafb71,5,HSQLDB Connections @60072ffb]]: database alias= does not exist
```

I am at a loss. Should I specify alias when connecting somehow? What alias would my database have then? The server did not say anything about that...

(also, yes I have copied the `sqltool.rc` file to my home folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server has `-dbname.0 xdb` as the database alias. Therefore the connection URL should include `xdb`. For example `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb`

The server can serve several databases with different aliases. The URL without alias corresponds to a server command line that does not include the alias setting.

Answer (score 4):

`java -jar /hsqldb-2.3.2/hsqldb/lib/sqltool.jar --inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:localhost:3333/runtime,user=sa
Enter password for sa:  as2dbadmin
SqlTool v. 5337.
JDBC Connection established to a HSQL Database Engine v. 2.3.2 database`

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This error has been hunting me for the last 5 hours.
Together with this stupid error: [HSQL Driver not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451570/hsql-driver-not-working#new-answer)

If you want to run your hsqldb on your servlet with Apache Tomcat it is necessary that you CLOSE the runManagerSwing.bat. I know it sounds trivial but even if you create the desired database and you run Eclipse J22 Servlet with Tomcat afterwards, you will get a bunch of errors. So runManagerSwing.bat must be closed.

Answer (score 0):

See my sqltool answer over on the question "[How to see all the tables in an HSQLDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19646240/226625)". The critical piece is setting up your sqltool.rc correctly and putting it in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following statement for getting a connection from a files based store. this can be used if you are running the application from Windows.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:///c:/hsqldb/mydb", "SA", "");
```