# Java - Writing a query to a database

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I am trying to write code to access a known database on my server to gather data from a certain table, but I keep getting an exception.

Here is my Java code so far;

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{ 
    String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:C:/workspace/database/eemdb";
    String dbName = "eem_db";
    String driver = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
    String username = "sa";
    String password = "";
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, username, password);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DEVICE");

        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is the exception report;

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DEVICE
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.davranetworks.seleniumtests.Example.main(Example.java:32)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DEVICE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
```

For the moment all I want to do is connect to the database and call a query but it just is not happening for me. Has any got any information to help me?

Comment: It seems like the table `DEVICE` does not exist in your database or you are not allowed to access it.

Comment: no it exists, I can enter it manually and I do have access to it

Comment: possibliy lacks a / in `url+dbName`

Comment: what is your db name?

Comment: Does that exact query work if you run it directly?   My first thought would be that you need to fully qualify DEVICE in your query.

Comment: `url+dbName = jdbc:hsqldb:C:/workspace/database/eemdbeem_db` pretty sure this is not intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error message might be misleading. Try a newer version of hsqldb (or switch to [the H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) to see what error messages should be like).

In your case, my guess is that table `DEVICE` does not exist. Did you create any tables in this database?

Also note that hsqldb will create an empty database if you make a typo in the URL.

The "user lacks privilege" is very unlikely since `sa` is the DB administrator.

To check which tables exist: [How to see all the tables in an HSQLDB database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591518/how-to-see-all-the-tables-in-an-hsqldb-database)

Comment: +1 for H2 Recommendation. It's a drop-in replacement for HSQLDB, but is WAY better.

Comment: This is a company database that my colleagues use so I can't make any changes to it.
The table `Device` does exist, I have tried the code with other tables but with the same result. I personally didn't create the tables

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to see which tables are in the database. My guess is that you made a typo and hsqldb created a new, empty database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created any tables in DB prior to executing the code? and If you DEVICE then there is probability that a **/** is missing try it like this

```
 String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:C://workspace/database/eemdb";
```

Comment: Tried it, it makes no difference