# Table not found in statement

Tags: java, database, eclipse, odb

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:Pokemondaten","sa","");
    getData = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = getData.executeQuery
    ("SELECT HP FROM PKMN WHERE ID = " + basicnumber); 
    int hpp = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.println(hpp);
```

all I get is

```
java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [SELECT HP FROM PKMN]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at pokeWpRechner.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

My Databased is called `Pokemondaten`and my table is called `PKMN`, also my table is inherited in the programm.

So what did i do wrong? i dont get it.

Comment: Check if your table is really there: [How to see all the tables in an HSQLDB database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/591518)

Comment: `java.sql.SQLException: No data is available` this does mean my database is not where i want it to be, doesnt it?

Comment: where do you create your table PKMN?

Comment: its already existent, built in OpenOffice Base and then added to the programm

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:Pokemondaten;shutdown=true","sa","")
```

This should prevent the table definition to being lost

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the full path to your database file in the JDBC URL:

`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:\mydir\Pokemondaten","sa","");`

Comment: thats what i tried to avoid :( i want the location of the DB top be flexible (where the program is) but i will try to get it running anyways

Comment: @Ekonion you should be able to get the current path from where your program is running like this: `Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString()` and then you can use this string to create an absolute path to your database file.

Comment: `java.sql.SQLException: No data is available` still