# The code when run opens the jdbc connection but it is not printing the table data.What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

```
package com.cg.tr.jdbc;
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.cg.trg.utilself.DBUtilSelf;

 public class MenuBase {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Connection connection = DBUtilSelf.openConnection();
 System.out.println("Connection opened");
 String sql="SELECT BNUM FROM BOOK";

try
 {
    Statement st=connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
    System.out.println("Book details");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.print(rs.getInt("BNUM")+"\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getString("BNAME")+"\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getFloat("BPRICE")+"\t");
        System.out.print(rs.getString("BAUTHOR")+"\t");
        System.out.println();
     }

}
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
    DBUtilSelf.closeConnection();
  } 

  }
 }
```

This code when run on eclipse does not print the data from table in oracle.
The output is:

Connection opened
Book details

It does not enter the while loop.Neither any exception is generated.I have made sure that column names from the table are written correctly.Still it does not give output

package com.cg.trg.utilself;

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DBUtilSelf 
 {

 static Connection connection;
 static String url;
 static String username;
 static String password;

 static
 {
    //load properties file...
    Properties prop =new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis;

    try
    {
    fis=new FileInputStream("jdbc.properties");
    prop.load(fis);
    }
   catch(IOException e)
    {
System.out.println("Problem while loading properties file:"+e.getMessage());

     }

 url=prop.getProperty("url");
 username=prop.getProperty("username");
password=prop.getProperty("password");

 }
 public static Connection openConnection()
 {
try
  {
   connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
  }
 catch(SQLException e)
 {
  System.out.println("Error while opening connection"+e.getMessage());
 }
return connection;
 }

public static void closeConnection()
{
    if(connection!=null)
    {
    try
    {
    connection.close();
    }
     catch(SQLException e)
     { 
    System.out.println("Error while closing connection:"+e.getMessage());
    }
    }
  }
  }
```

This is the DBUtilSelf.java file

Comment: Because the table is empty?

Comment: Clearly, rs gives no data.

Comment: select * from book;

      BNUM BNAME                    BPRICE BAUTHOR
---------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
      1001 Let Us C                   1200 Yashvant Kanetkar
      1002 Core JAVA               2100.65 H.Schild
      1003 J2EE                       2450 H.Schild
      1004 Computer Networks          2200 Tanenbaum
      1005 Operating System           3290 Millan
      1006 Algorithms                 1900 Coreman
      1007 Complete C++            1750.55 Yashvant Kanetkar

7 rows selected.The table is not empty

Comment: What does 'SELECT BNUM FROM BOOK' give?

Comment: It gives all the booknums                                                                                                     BNUM
----------
      1001
      1002
      1003
      1004
      1005
      1006
      1007

Comment: Why are you selecting one column but then printing other coulums that don't exist in the rs?

Comment: I tried with select * from book also in the main program,but still no results.How come rs is not getting any data?

Comment: Can you post the content of  this method as well DBUtilSelf.openConnection();

Comment: Which DB is underline? Isn't ';' missing at the end of the statement?

Comment: I have added the DBUtilSelf.java file

Comment: where is ';' missing?

Comment: Try to add "dbName." before BOOK; where dbName si the name of your database.

Comment: I added the dbName : SELECT * FROM ORCL.BOOK               Connection opened
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:461)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:402)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1108)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:541)
 com.cg.trg.jdbcdemos.MenuBase.main(MenuBase.java:18)

Answer (score 0):

The code was right but the only problem was that after creating table in sql,it was not commited. Using the commit query in sql saves the changes in the database so that they can be visible through jdbc.

Comment: I think this cannot be the case. If a table is not committed to a database, then it's not physically available i.e. it's absent. Since it's not available/committed and in such case, if one tries to access it an exception will be thrown like: `java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [SELECT BNUM FROM BOOK]` for that [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190278/table-not-found-in-statement). By the way, this isn't a solution for this scenario.