# OpenOffice Base - Merge >200 tables into one

Tags: merge, openoffice-base

I am new to OpenOffice Base. In a couple of hours I will have about 290 tables with identical headers. What is the quickest and easiest way to merge all these into one (1) single table?

Comment: What is your database engine -- for example MySQL, PostgreSQL, or the built-in HSQLDB 1.8?

Comment: I have just installed the OpenOffice Basic. I would assume that it makes use of the built in HSQLDB 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools -> SQL` and use the [CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php) syntax.  A command like this one can quickly be created for all 290 tables using a decent text editor such as Vim.

```
create table Table3 as
select * from Table1
union select * from Table2
union select * from Table3
union select * from Table4;
```

To see the new table, go to `View -> Refresh Tables`.

This example was tested with MySQL.  The syntax may be different depending on the database engine.

**EDIT**:

The command above does not work for HSQLDB 1.8, so you must be using a different engine.  How did you set up the connection?

Anyway, for all available table names in MySQL, see [Get table names using SELECT statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql).  For HSQLDB see [How to see all the tables in an HSQLDB database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591518/how-to-see-all-the-tables-in-an-hsqldb-database)

Comment: Works, but messes up my data. Sh**, I didn't think of that. The records to throw into one table are "bills of material". If each record would contain the original table name then the above "union" would be perfect.
I had to create a table and used...

INSERT INTO "T"
SELECT * FROM "16330000"
UNION SELECT * FROM "16630020"
....);

Comment: I am working my way through the problem. Made myself a macro to modify "a" table: Drop column, add column, update the added column with table name. It works, but...
How on earth can I iterate through which list of all available tables?